# Комп на H77-DS3H начал глючить

Tags: ubuntu, железо

Комп, конечно старый, блок питания восстанавливался, винчестер тоже поизносился. Стоит убунта 20.04 и виндовс 10, и то и то загружается и работает некоторое время, потом отваливается мыш и клава, может на экране что зря появиться, а система еще некоторое время обращается к винчестеру. Смотрел логи,

```
    [    0.131889] core: PMU erratum BJ122, BV98, HSD29 workaround disabled, HT off
[    0.147009] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.162177] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKA configured for IRQ 11
[    0.162246] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKB configured for IRQ 10
[    0.162311] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKC configured for IRQ 11
[    0.162375] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKD configured for IRQ 5
[    0.162440] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKE configured for IRQ 0
[    0.162441] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKE disabled
[    0.162504] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKF configured for IRQ 0
[    0.162505] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKF disabled
[    0.162567] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKG configured for IRQ 3
[    0.162631] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKH configured for IRQ 10
[    0.322830] fbcon: Deferring console take-over
[    1.522349] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: SMBus using PCI interrupt
[   46.344896] EXT4-fs (sda9): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
```

критического не нашел. sda9 - раздел убунты. Думаю, что дело не в математике - системы совсем разные и ведут себя одинаково! Я в линуксе не разбираюсь, вот при загрузке появляются такие сообщения: recovering journal и clean для раздела с убунтой - тоже не критично.
посоветуйте: стоит с ним возиться или собирать на новую машину, так мне этого хватало, было 8 гиг памяти, одну планку вытащил - тест памяти зависал на первой же секунде, 4 гига осталось - мало, debug d андроид студии не идет! Если тратиться на эту машину - придется еще DDR3 покупать и главное - где копать?

Comment: Ну а винт проверял? Только оператива глючит?

Comment: Винчестер тоже старый, проверял. После проверки пришлось груб восстанавливать. При каждой загрузке находит на sda9 раздел убуты, сбойные блоки. Наверно, дешевл будет новый собрать? Он и здесь выдает re mounted!

Comment: Ты псал, что с одной плашкой памяти тормозит, но работает. Так там тоже сбоит или просто всё медленно?

Comment: В том то и дело, что сбоит, время от времени. Еслиб работал нормально добавил бы памяти. Думаю, если заменить бланк питания, оп и винчестер ещё поработает, а может лучше сразу собирать на новый, это не меньше 30 тыщ, замена на старом наполовину дешевле примерно будет, вот и думаю?

Comment: Этот вот выдает разные dependency failet for swap, home, local file system при загрузке частенько!

Comment: Ну новый БП и ссд в любом случае переедут дальше, если соберёшься таки апгрейдиться. Так что да, можно заменить сначала их и посмотреть исчезнут ошибки или нет.

Comment: Ссд у меня не стоит, там как я понял он используется как кеш, винчесер можно заменить, потом пригодится и бп, ддр3 уже устарело! Видео, которая на плате почему то не работает, хотел вытащить видеокарту, чтобы нагрузку уменьшить и посмотреть как без нее, или чтобы заработала родная видео нужно видеокарту вытащить?

Comment: Эээ... если встроенное видео не работает (с вытащенной дискретной видюхой) - тут ровно 2 варианта. 1. Ты что-то неправильно делаешь - или не туда тыкаешь шнур монитора или что-то натыкал в биосе. 2. Мать и\или проц почти сдохли.

Comment: Скорее всего вариант 2. Шнур монитора в другое место не воткнещь. Биос простой ф2, там про видео ничего не видно. Я плату видео не вытаскивал, может из за этого не работает?

Comment: Ну так материнка находит отдельное видео и если в биосе не настроено iGPU или AUTO - то конечно на разём вга на матери ничего выдаваться не будет.

Comment: Надо же! Раз,ему впаяны и отключаются! А если новый комп брать, какие сейчас в ходу, меня игры не интересуют, но чтобы лет на 5 не задумываться и сумма, не знаю, тыс 40 на приличны не офисный хватит. На 500 чипсет сколько нужно, не вкурсе?

Comment: По железу не особо. Но докупить ssd и свежий БП - никогда лишним не будет.

Comment: Спасибо большое!